# How to validate ajax form with onclick event on submit by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I have a simple domain whois form:

```
<form id="domaincheck" class="form-inline ltr" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control center input-md" name="sld" id="sld" placeholder="pleade enter domain name" required>
    <select class="form-control ltr input-md input-group-addon" id="tld" name="tld" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="com" selected="">.com</option>
        <option value="ir">.ir</option>
        <option value="net">.net</option>
        <option value="org">.org</option>
        <option value="co">.co</option>
        <option value="xyz">.xyz</option>
        <option value="biz">.biz</option>
        <option value="info">.info</option>
        <option value="asia">.asia</option>
        <option value="us">.us</option>
        <option value="mobi">.mobi</option>
        <option value="name">.name</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="get_whois()">check!</button>
</form>
```

and use [jquery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/methods/) to validate.
I have added this code to validate input to set minimum chars must be 4.

```
$("#domaincheck").validate({
    rules: {
        sld: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4
        }
    },
    messages: {
        sld: {
            required: "Please input domain name!",
            minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, at least {0} characters are necessary")
        }
    }
});
```

Now how to disable button that have onclick event to avoid send request until input be valid.
and also add rule to say just these characters ( a-z A-z and "-" ) is valid to type in input.

Any Help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Click Here For Demo JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Hussy/bh4r5uyb/)

```
$.validator.addMethod("sldRegex", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z\-]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Username must contain only letters, numbers, or dashes.");
$("#domaincheck").validate({
        rules: {
            sld: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                sldRegex: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            sld: {
                required: "Please input domain name!",
                minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, at least {0} characters are necessary")
            }
        }
        ,submitHandler: function(form) {

                    form.submit() ; 
                }
    });
```

Comment: thank you but I have to use type="button" for button and It's an ajax form that call request by onclick event. immediately after click onclick event send request. also submit type for button make redirect and refresh page.

Comment: So You can put your ajax request inside submitHandler: function(form) {

                   //code here
                }

Comment: Thanks You. Great Job!